# Scheduled Facebook posts using JS API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to write a client-side JS function to send a post to a Facebook Fanpage at a specific time using [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). It used to be possible with the old JS SDK. Was that changed?
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posts require access_token and access tokens have about 2 hour expire time.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use FB.ui() with scheduled posting since it will require an actual user log in when posting. You can use FB.api() for this and pass the user/page access token in the parameters.. for the actual code for scheduled posting, I haven't done it myself but for posting, here you go.

```js
try {
  var pageId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  var obj = {
    name: name,
    description: description,
    link: link,
    picture: picture,
    caption: caption,
    access_token: pageAccessToken
  };

  FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed', 'POST', obj, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      // do something
      return;
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  });
} catch (e) {}
```